# what's differences between "forms timeout", "membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow" and "sessionState timeout"

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, session-state

What is the difference between these lines of code:

```
<forms timeout="5" />

<membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="5" />

<sessionState timeout="5" />
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry are you an msdn free workplace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Forms** ([FormsAuthention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3fc21xw.aspx)) are used for authentication and when it times out it will logout user. You can 'prevent' timeout by setting **SlidingExpiration** property to 'true' and it will renew forms ticket on user activity (read request to asp) if needed. This will keep user logged on while he is 'active' on your site.

**[Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx)** is used for user validation and **userIsOnlineTimeWindow** is there to help you track user activity so when it runs out it will set **IsOnline** property to 'false' for that user. One new thing I found out is that it *will also renew* forms ticket while users isOnline is set, main difference is that it *doesn't* renew *itself* automatically but only when its **GetUser()** or **ValidateUser()** methods are run.

When **session** times out you will lose data found in **[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)** object. That is all.

Comment: @AranMulholland And garabage collector will clear memory and at some point some man in China will sneeze.

Comment: and That is all? Too funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the following behavior:

You set Session timeout = 10 minutes and Forms Authentication timeout = 8 minutes.

The user logs into your site using Forms Authentication.

Both the Session "clock" and Forms Authentication "clock" start running.

Suppose that you keep some info needed for the site's operation in the Session(For example, Session["userData"] = userData;).

The user is idle for 9 minutes.

At 8 minutes the session times out and the user's data is cleared.

At 9 minutes when the user tries to perform some activity on the site, you naively reference the Session["userData"] to get his info. Since it is null he will get error 500 for a null reference.

Conclusion: Keep the forms authentication timeout shorter than the session timeout.