# Facing session issue in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am using Asp.Net Membership and when user enters correct username and password I sign him in using:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String, Boolean)
```

If I create a persistent cookie then I think my membership will still be able to work but my session data will be null.

This is really annonying and introducing a whole lot of bugs in my application. How can I handle this?

Should I handle global.asax's Application_AuthenticateRequest and check if the userId which I store in session is null and `Membership.GetUser()` is not null, then I should store ProviderUserKey (Guid) again in Session.

Is this a reasonable approach or is there any better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your session and authcookie's life-time in your `web.config` file. See:

```
<forms timeout="5" />

<sessionState timeout="5" />
```

> Forms are used for authentication and when it times out it will logout
>   user. You can 'prevent' timeout by setting SlidingExpiration property
>   to 'true' and it will renew forms ticket on user activity (read
>   request to asp) if needed. This will keep user logged on while he is
>   'active' on your site.

and

> When session times out you will lose data found in Session object.

Your problem may may be of this issue. Your auth-cookie is alive, but the session is timed-out. User is logged-in, but the session-variables are destroyed! Check this configuration in your app.

---

[See this Q also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900512/whats-differences-between-forms-timeout-membership-userisonlinetimewindow-a)

Comment: I don't want want to set the forms and sessionState timeout to same. What if they are different? How can I then again set the data in session? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: if the session timed-out, you must fill it's data again. or you can put the light-data in cookies instead of session. for example I usually save the first-name, last-name, email, etc, in cookies. also you can put heavy data in cookie, but not recommended, also, it is not recommended to put heavy objects in session. so 1- if you have light data, put them in cookies (instead of session) 2- if you have big and heavy objects, it's better that you select them from database, when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use session for it instead of cookie.
And according to me that should be not preferable to save ProviderUserKey in session or any where.
Use global.asax(Application_AuthenticateRequest) for check authentication and based on that id, get ProviderUserKey from DB.

Hope my comment is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

sessions and authcookies are different. authcookies life-time can be set in `forms timeout="5"` config-section and sessions life-time should be set in `sessionState timeout="5"` config-section. It is possible that an auth-cookie is persist yet, but the session expires. Check this.

Comment: Your "Check this" at the end means what? I understand auth cookie is persist. So how I can again set the data in session? What is the best way to do that?